# Any suggestions on how to compute $\limsup |\cos n|^{n^2}$?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometric-series, diophantine-approximation

This problem has proven very difficult, does anyone have any suggestions on how to tackle it? Any little known theorems/identities that might help?

Comment: Would you like to share your thought on the problem? It is easy to show this limsup is non-zero.

Comment: Based on the continued fraction approximations of $\pi$ I'd expect it to be at least $\exp(-\pi^2/8)$.

Comment: And the given problem is *equivalent* to finding the $\limsup$ of the terms of the continued fraction of $\pi$. This still is an open problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us consider the continued fraction of $\pi$:
$$ \pi = [3; 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14,\ldots]$$
together with its convergents $\frac{p_1}{q_1}=\frac{22}{7},\frac{p_2}{q_2}=\frac{333}{106},\frac{p_3}{q_3}=\frac{355}{113}$ etcetera.
The sequence $\{p_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ provides a set of natural numbers where the cosine function attains values estremely close to $\pm 1$. By the properties of continued fractions we have $\left|\frac{p_n}{q_n}-\pi\right|\leq \frac{1}{q_n^2}$, hence $\left|p_n-\pi q_n\right|\leq \frac{1}{q_n}\approx\frac{\pi}{p_n}$ and by the Lipshitz-continuity of $\sin$

$$\left|\cos(p_n)\right|^{p_n^2}=\left(1-\sin^2 p_n\right)^{p_n^2/2} \approx \left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{p_n^2}\right)^{p_n^2/2}\to e^{-\pi^2/\color{red}{2}}\geq \frac{1}{140}$$
so the wanted $\limsup$ is at least as large as $\frac{1}{140}$. On the other hand, if we assume that the terms of the continued fraction of $\pi$ are *unbounded*, the constant $2$ above can be replaced by any larger constant and the wanted $\limsup$ is just one. The pity is we do not actually know if the terms of the continued fraction of $\pi$ are unbounded or not. For sure, if we consider $n=710$ the value of $\left|\cos n\right|^{n^2}$ is very close to $1$, being equal to $\approx 0.999084$. Additionally, since $\pi\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, infinite terms of the continued fraction of $\pi$ are $\geq 2$, from which we have WimC's claim
$$ \limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|\cos(n)\right|^{n^2}\geq e^{-\pi^2/8}>\frac{23}{79}.$$
Following the same lines we have
$$ \limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|\cos\frac{\pi n}{e}\right|^{n^2}=1$$
since the terms of the continued fraction of $e$ *are* unbounded, due to
$$ e=[2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1,1,10,\ldots].$$

Comment: At least terms $\geq 2$ must occur infinitely often. That's where my denominator $8$ came from.

Comment: @WimC: agreed (otherwise $\pi$ would be algebraic with degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, precisely of the form $a+b\sqrt{5}$). If you like it, feel free to improve the answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I have proved the same result, but with a different method: by using the 2nd degree Taylor expansion of $\cos$. Fascinating proof using with denominator 8 though!

Comment: @SullyChen: I would be curious to know how the Taylor series of $\cos$ were used for describing the behaviour of $\cos$ over the integers, but anyway I am pleased you found this useful.

Comment: Here is the paper I wrote with my professor on the topic: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02955, which includes the Taylor series proof! Your proof with Lipshitz continuity is much more elegant, though.

Comment: Well, of course, if $\pi$ is a badly approximable number (meaning that the terms of the continued fraction are bounded) its irrationality measure is $2$, but the behaviour of the initial terms of some subsequences of $\cos(n)^{n^\gamma}$ does not *prove* much about $\mu(\pi)$, it just shows that it is reasonable to conjecture that $\mu(\pi)=2$. I do not see anything in the linked article disproving the existence of infinite terms of the continued fraction of $\pi$ greater than, let's say, $290$.

Comment: This is great. I'm sure this is basic stuff, but I have forgotten. How exactly did the terms of the continued fraction show up in the estimates again? If a term of size $M$ shows up infinitely often then $|p_n-\pi q_n|\le\dfrac1{Mq_n}$ or?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: exactly. This happens since a more accurate bound for $\left|\alpha-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|$ is given by $\frac{1}{q_n q_{n+1}}$ and $q_{n+1}=a_n q_n + q_{n-1}$.

Comment: Oh yeah. That rings a bell. Thanks, Jack!

Comment: Markov spectrum and transcendence of pi give us $\left|\frac{p_n}{q_n}-\pi\right|\leq \frac{1}{3q_n^2}$ (I don't have time to read the proof so I hope I didn't miss something) so we should get $e^{-\pi^2/18}\approx 0.5579$