# When does the limit $|\cos(n)|^{f(n)}$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty, n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

Here we go with a *not-so-trivial* problem:

Inspired by another problem that I myself asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897635/does-the-limit-of-cos2nn-n-a-positive-integer-converge-as-n-to-inft), I came with this more general formulation: Let be the sequence $a(n) = |\cos(n)|^{f(n)}$. Then, when does the sequence $|\cos(n)|^{f(n)}$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$? And the only thing that we may vary is $f(n)$. The only constrain for $f(n)$ will be that $f(n)$ **increases monotonically** and is **unbounded**.

It is easy to see that the numbers that belong to the open interval $(k\pi, (k+1)\pi)$ tend to $0$ as $f(n) \rightarrow \infty$. And on the other side, all natural numbers will always belong to these intervals (if not, that would be equivalent to claim the rationality of $\pi$). Then, all members of the sequence will tend to $0$...   ***All??*** Not necessarily, because by [Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), you can always find an integer that is arbitrarily close to a multiple of $\pi$. And the closer you are to a multiple of $\pi$, the closer would be the following and related function to 1:

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow k\pi} |\cos(x)| = 1
$$

On the other hand, if instead of considering functions with real numbers, we focus on our sequence over the natural numbers, we can see that not all the integers approximate to a multiple of $\pi$ in the same manner. There is an integer sequence that every member of the sequence is closer to a multiple of $\pi$ that the previous member (https://oeis.org/A046947). This integer sequence increases exponentially and let be $b(n)$ that sequence. I've seen computationally, that $b(n) \approx \pi^n$. So...

As I can see this, here there are to different *opposing forces* acting one against the other to make converge or diverge our sequence. On one side, the *convergence speed* of the members of the open intervals $(k\pi, (k+1)\pi)$ towards $0$ ($k\in\mathbb{N}$), which we can control through playing with $f(n)$; and on the other side, the *convergence speed* of the sequence $b(n)$ to a bigger multiple of $\pi$. but this "process" is fixed and we cannot alter it.

It seems that:

$$
f(n) = 2n \implies \nexists  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\cos(n)|^{f(n)} 
$$
This problem seem to be [solved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897635/does-the-limit-of-cos2nn-n-a-positive-integer-converge-as-n-to-inft) in my previous MSE question. This shows an example of $f(n)$ that makes this sequence diverge, but I strongly think that other expressions for $f(n)$ can make this sequence converge to $0$. My intuition tells me that if $f(n)$ is linear, the sequence will diverge always, but I have that feeling that tells me that if $f(n)$ is **exponential**, like $f(n) = a^n$, then the sequence will converge if $a > a_0$, being $a_0$ some constant (maybe $\pi$?).

So the final question to answer would be:

> Let $f(n)$ be a **monotonically increasing** and **unbounded** sequence whose expression is known. How must be $f(n)$ so: $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\cos(n)|^{f(n)} = 0? $$

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I maybe missing something here, but doesn't irrationality of $\pi$ imply that $|cos(n)|<1$ for any natural $n$? Thus $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\cos(n)|^n = 0$

Comment: @Vasya Your conclusion doesn't hold in general. Consider $(\frac{1}{2^{1/n}})^n$ as a counterexample.

Comment: For example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871833/any-suggestions-on-how-to-compute-limsup-cos-nn2

Answer (score 1):

**An example faster than $2n$**

Here, we take $f(n)=n^2$. We claim that there are infinitely many pairs of positive integers $(n,k)$ such that 
$$
|n-2\pi k|\leq \frac1{k}.
$$
This is achieved if $\frac nk$ is a simple continued fraction convergents of $2\pi$.

Then we have 
$$
\cos\frac1k = 1-\frac1{2k^2} +O(\frac1{k^4}).
$$

Thus, the same arguments (in Jack D'Aurizio's answer) as in the link you provided, we see that for any $\epsilon>0$ 
there are infinitely many pairs $(n,k)$ such that 
$$
|\cos n|^{k^2}\geq e^{-1/2}-\epsilon.
$$
Since $k\asymp n$, we see that 
$$
|\cos n|^{n^2} 
$$
is greater than a fixed positive number when $n\rightarrow \infty$ along the numerators of convergents of $2\pi$.

Along with the existence of infinitely many $n$ such that $|\cos n|\leq 1/2$, we see that 
$$
|\cos n|^{n^2}
$$
does not tend to a limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

**A polynomial function with convergence to zero**

Since $\pi$ has a finite irrationality measure (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html)), the inequality
$$
|n-\pi k| > \frac1{k^{\mu + \epsilon -1}}
$$
for all sufficiently large integers $n,k$. Here, we use $\mu=7.6063$.

Let $f(n)=n^{2(\mu+2\epsilon-1)}$. Then there is a fixed positive $c$ such that
$$
|\cos n|^{f(n)} \leq \left|1-\frac c{n^{2(\mu+\epsilon -1)}} \right|^{f(n)}\rightarrow 0.
$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from being an expert here, but I suspect that there is no explicit answer known. The problem is that if $n$ is very close to $k\pi$ then $|\cos(n)|$ is very close to $1$, so $f(n)$ has to be very large in order to make $|\cos(n)|^{f(n)}$ small.

So given a sequence $f(n)$, in order to determine whether $|\cos(n)|^{f(n)}$ tends to zero we need fairly precise information about the behavior of the sequence $\delta_n$ defined by $\delta_n=\min_{k\in\Bbb Z}|n-k\pi|$; my impression is that we don't know enough about this sequence.

Comment: I suspect that it can be easy to find a sequence $\gamma_n \geq  \delta_n$, but well defined. I suspect that it shouldn't be difficult to find such sequence, and use is to bound or characterize $f(n)$... I think

Comment: @CarlosToscano-Ochoa You may be right - let us know...